# Create NSArray of keywords starting/ending with % inside a string

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsarray

I have a long string that contain keywords that start and end with the percent sign. E.g.:

> My name is `%user_username%` and I live at `%location_address%`. You can
>   reach me at `%user_phone%`.

**What method would I use to extract all strings that begin and end with `%` and put those into an `NSArray` so that I can replace them with their correct text representations?**

Comment: you can loop through the characters in your string, each time you reach a % character you create a new NSMutableString and start appending to it the character that follow until you reach the next % character add your NSMutableString to your array

Comment: That sounds like sort of an expensive operation.

Comment: You could use NSRegularExpression "%.*?%" and `-[matchesInString:options:range:]`

Comment: That's what `NSScanner` is for

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there are no `%` signs inside your strings of interest (e.g "a%ab%b%c"), you could use the `componentsSeparatedByString:` or `componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:` to get an array of strings separated by the `%` sign. From there, it's pretty easy to figure out which strings in that array are between the percent signs, and which are unnecessary.

I think internally though, those methods are likely implemented as something like a loop looking for `%`s. Maybe they parallelize the search on big strings, or use special knowledge of the internal structure of the string to make things faster -- those are the only ways I can see to speed up the search, assuming that you're stuck with keeping it all in a `%` delimited string (if speed is really an issue, then the answer is probably to use an alternative representation).

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with that works:

```
- (NSArray *)replaceKeywords:(NSString *)keywordString {

    NSString *start =   @"%";
    NSString *end =     @"%";
    NSMutableArray* strings = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];

    NSRange startRange = [keywordString rangeOfString:start];

    for( ;; ) {

        if (startRange.location != NSNotFound) {

            NSRange targetRange;

            targetRange.location = startRange.location + startRange.length;
            targetRange.length = [keywordString length] - targetRange.location;

            NSRange endRange = [keywordString rangeOfString:end options:0 range:targetRange];

            if (endRange.location != NSNotFound) {

                targetRange.length = endRange.location - targetRange.location;
                [strings addObject:[keywordString substringWithRange:targetRange]];

                NSRange restOfString;

                restOfString.location = endRange.location + endRange.length;
                restOfString.length = [keywordString length] - restOfString.location;

                startRange = [keywordString rangeOfString:start options:0 range:restOfString];

            } else {
                break;
            }

        } else {
            break;
        }

    }

    return strings;

}
```

I slightly modified the method from [Get String Between Two Other Strings in ObjC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002360/get-string-between-two-other-strings-in-objc)