# Get Array of Strings In Between Two Strings with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

This question has been asked a few times before, [here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5642315/regular-expression-to-get-a-string-between-two-strings-in-javascript). However, the question linked only asks about getting one string out of the result. The text I would like to parse has many different instances of the trailing and leading strings, and thus the code below does not work:

```
test.match("SomeString(.*)TrailingString");
```

As shown in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uwoqukv3/). I will show you the intended result below:

If I were to have a string composed of the following elements `STARTINGTEXTText I wantENDINGTEXT Text I don't want STARTINGTEXTMore text I wantENDINGTEXT Text I don't want`

I would like to have a function that I can pass in the arguments `STARTINGTEXT` and `ENDINGTEXT` and it would return an array with `"Text I want"` and `"More text I want"`

Thanks!

**EDIT** - This is a Pebble Application so JQuery isn't an option.

This similar thing has been done in [Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002360/get-string-between-two-other-strings-in-objc):

```
-(NSMutableArray*)stringsBetweenString:(NSString*)start andString:(NSString*)end
{

  NSMutableArray* strings = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];

  NSRange startRange = [self rangeOfString:start];

  for( ;; )
  {

    if (startRange.location != NSNotFound)
    {

      NSRange targetRange;

      targetRange.location = startRange.location + startRange.length;
      targetRange.length = [self length] - targetRange.location;   

      NSRange endRange = [self rangeOfString:end options:0 range:targetRange];

      if (endRange.location != NSNotFound)
      {

        targetRange.length = endRange.location - targetRange.location;
        [strings addObject:[self substringWithRange:targetRange]];

        NSRange restOfString;

        restOfString.location = endRange.location + endRange.length;
        restOfString.length = [self length] - restOfString.location;

        startRange = [self rangeOfString:start options:0 range:restOfString];

      }
      else
      {
        break;
      }

    }
    else
    {
      break;
    }

  }

  return strings;

}
```

Comment: so you want to keep things between opening and closing tags, but not between closing and opening tags? Is there a reason you can't just use an XML parser (which you clearly need here, don't use regex for parsing markup) to throw away all "untagged" content?

Comment: The example I gave with tags wasn't a very good one. I'll add another to make it clearer.

Comment: You should start by using regex literals instead of string literals for regular expressions.

Comment: @AlexWulff never show "something like" what you're working with. Show *what you're working with* =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would prefer a RegExp solution, you could do something like this:

```
var test = "STARTINGTEXTText I wantENDINGTEXT Text I don't want STARTINGTEXTMore text I wantENDINGTEXT Text I don't want";
var matches = test.match(/STARTINGTEXT(.*?)ENDINGTEXT/g);
```

The key to this is the "g" (or global) flag, and the non-greedy repeat operator "*?". See this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) for an explanation of the "g" flag and the non-greedy operator.

Here is a modification of your fiddle: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/uwoqukv3/5/). I changed it so that the alert would show a stringified JSON of the results, so that you could see it matching both strings.

Answer (score 1):

This methodology uses very little code:

```
function getBetweenText(fromString, ignoreStart, ignoreEnd){
  var s =  fromString.split(new RegExp(ignoreStart+'|'+ignoreEnd)), r = [];
  for(var i=1,l=s.length; i<l; i+=2){
    r.push(s[i]);
  }
  return r;
}
console.log(getBetweenText("STARTINGTEXTText I wantENDINGTEXT Text I don't want STARTINGTEXTMore text I wantENDINGTEXT Text I don't want", 'STARTINGTEXT', 'ENDINGTEXT'));
```

Comment: Thank you - this is also helpful because it gets rid of the starting and ending strings

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using jQuery. To select all the elements with specific tag you just do something like this: ** UPDATED WITH NON-JQUERY VERSION **

```
var HTMLelements = document.getElementsByTagName("tag");
var results = [];
for(var i = 0; i < HTMLelements.length; i++){
  results.push(HTMLelements[i].innerHTML);
}
```

Comment: Sorry - I forgot to mention that this is for a Pebble application and thus I can't use JQuery. My mistake!

Comment: Updated with plain HTML

Comment: Is there a way to acomplish this where you can supply a unique ending tag?

Comment: Where the beginning string and ending string are different.

Comment: I am not quiet sure what do you mean by that. Do you have an example?

Comment: I'll add the example to my question